# sum and conditionally count based on a second column

Tags: r, sum, dplyr

I have gotten frustrated trying to solve this seemingly simple problem. I have a dataset (df) like this:

```
structure(list(Year = c(2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L), Unknown = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), Temp = c(21L, 21L, 21L, 23L, 23L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 21L, 23L, 
23L, 22L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 21L, 21L, 23L, 23L), Obs = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("mdk", "sde"), class = "factor"), State = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "ma", class = "factor"), Zone = c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), Segment = c(8L, 7L, 4L, 17L, 18L, 7L, 2L, 12L, 1L, 17L, 
18L, 12L, 9L, 7L, 13L, 11L, 8L, 9L, 17L, 18L), Subseg = c(1L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 10L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), Wdir = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("na", 
"ne", "nw"), class = "factor"), Wvel = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("5", "na"), class = "factor"), Clouds = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "4", "na"), class = "factor"), Temp.1 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("20", "25", "na"), class = "factor"), 
Species = structure(c(7L, 21L, 1L, 21L, 16L, 4L, 16L, 6L, 
1L, 17L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 24L, 5L), .Label = c("ABDU", 
                                                                                                      "ABDU", "ABDU", "ABDU", "ABDU", "CAGO", "CAGO", "CAGO", "CAGO", 
                                                                                                      "CAGO", "GOLD", "GOLD", "GOLD", "GOLD", "GOLD", "MERG", "MERG", 
                                                                                                      "MERG", "MERG", "MERG", "SCOT", "SCOT", "SCOT", "SCOT", 
                                                                                                      "SCOT", "SCOT", "SCOT"), class = "factor"), Count = c(5L, 
1L, 150L, 3L, 20L, 8L, 5L, 10L, 5L, 1L, 20L, 10L, 2L, 2L, 
80L, 40L, 1L, 1000L, 2L, 20L)), .Names = c("Year", "Unknown", 
"Temp", "Obs", "State", "Zone", "Segment", "Subseg", "Wdir", 
"Wvel", "Clouds", "Temp.1", "Species", "Count"), row.names = c(666L, 
614L, 2060L, 1738L, 1459L, 536L, 197L, 2467L, 98L, 1794L, 1449L, 
2464L, 696L, 483L, 2644L, 2350L, 686L, 844L, 2989L, 2934L), class = "data.frame")
```

With a header that looks like this:

```
 Year Unknown Temp Obs State Zone Segment Subseg Wdir Wvel
666  2015       1   21 mdk    ma    2       8      1   ne    5
614  2015       1   21 mdk    ma    2       7      3   ne    5
2060 2015       1   21 sde    ma    2       4      3   na   na
1738 2015       1   23 mdk    ma    2      17      2   nw    5
1459 2015       1   23 mdk    ma    2      18      2   nw    5
536  2015       1   21 mdk    ma    2       7      2   ne    5
 Clouds Temp.1 Species Count
666       1     20    CAGO     5
614       1     20    SCOT     1
2060     na     na    ABDU   150
1738      1     20    SCOT     3
1459      1     20    MERG    20
536       1     20    ABDU     8
```

Among other things within dplyr, I want to get a sum of each species as a new column, when I am grouping by segment. This is the final code I have tried with many variations.

```
df_group = df %>%
  group_by(Segment) %>%
  summarise(temp = round(mean(Temp)),   
            WDir = round(mean(Wdir)),
            ABDU = sum(which(Species=="ABDU"),Count),
            CAGO = sum(which(Species=="CAGO"),Count),
            GOLD = sum(which(Species=="GOLD"),Count),
            MERG = sum(which(Species=="MERG"),Count),
            SCOT = sum(which(Species=="SCOT"),Count))
```

And this is what I get (to show correct format):

```
Segment temp WDir ABDU CAGO GOLD MERG SCOT
1       1   21    2    6    5    5    5    5
2       2   21    2    5    5    5    6    5
3       4   21    1  151  150  150  150  150
4       7   21    2   16   11   11   11   12
5       8   21    2    6    9    6    6    6
6       9   21    2 1003 1004 1002 1002 1002
```

The format and general idea are what I want, but the numbers are not adding up the way I want them to. I'm sure it is simple but need some help! Thanks.

Comment: perhaps, what you want to do is `sum(Count[which(Species=="ABDU")])`

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I thought it was simple.

Comment: If you want to count every species, you might also have luck with `reshape2::dcast()` rather than typing out `Species == "x"` for all of your species.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that which returns a vector of the positions, but you're not using those to subset. So the sum you are getting is of the positions which are true in addition to the count variable. e.g.

```
x <- c("a", "b", "b")
count <- c(10, 11, 12)
sum(which(c("a", "b", "b") == "b"), count)
# 38 because it is 2 + 3 + 10 + 11 + 12
```

I believe what you want is (or at least one way of writing it):

```
sum(ifelse(x == "b", count, 0))
# 23 because it is equal to 0 + 11 + 12
```

Translating into dplyr syntax, your example could look like this:

```
df_group = df %>%
  group_by(Segment) %>%
  summarise(temp = round(mean(Temp)),   
            WDir = round(mean(Wdir)),
            ABDU = sum(ifelse(Species=="ABDU", Count, 0L)),
            CAGO = sum(ifelse(Species=="CAGO", Count, 0L)),
            GOLD = sum(ifelse(Species=="GOLD", Count, 0L)),
            MERG = sum(ifelse(Species=="MERG", Count, 0L)),
            SCOT = sum(ifelse(Species=="SCOT", Count, 0L)))
```

Comment: `sum(Count[Species=="ABDU"])` is a simpler way of doing the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, in case you don't want to type out the sum for all your species:

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
# I had a problem with duplicate factor levels from your dput,
# so I re-factored species
df$Species = as.factor(as.character(df$Species))

species.counts = select(df, Segment, Species, Count) %>%
    dcast(formula = Segment ~ Species, value.var = "Count", fun.aggregate = sum)

> head(species.counts)
   Segment ABDU CAGO MERG SCOT
1        1    5    0    0    0
2        2    0    0    5    0
3        4  150    0    0    0
4        7   10    0    0    1
5        8    0    6    0    0
6        9    2 1000    0    0

df %>% group_by(Segment) %>%
    summarise(temp = round(mean(Temp))) %>%
    left_join(species.counts)

Source: local data frame [11 x 6]

   Segment temp ABDU CAGO MERG SCOT
1        1   21    5    0    0    0
2        2   21    0    0    5    0
3        4   21  150    0    0    0
4        7   21   10    0    0    1
5        8   21    0    6    0    0
6        9   21    2 1000    0    0
```

I also couldn't do the wind direction average, because your `dput` data only has that as a factor with the directions, not like the `head()` you showed, but the technique generalizes.