# dplyr - from group_by into own function

Tags: r

This is quite possibly a duplicate of either or both of these, if so apologies and I guess that would make it an outstanding burning issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388211/in-r-package-dplyr-how-to-use-own-defined-function-to-summarise-each

[pass grouped dataframe to own function in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28201066/pass-grouped-dataframe-to-own-function-in-dplyr)

Using plyr one could run something like this:

```
ddply(mtcars, .(cyl), function(x) table(x$am))
```

and get the nice output

```
> ddply(mtcars, .(cyl), function(x) table(x$am))
  cyl  0 1
1   4  3 8
2   6  4 3
3   8 12 2
```

I still don't really get why `ddply(mtcars, .(cyl), table(am))` doesn't work, but nevermind.

Is there a way to achieve the above in dplyr?

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  function(x) table(x$am)
```

Doesn't achieve the same results.

UPDATED QUESTION (leaving the above for historical purposes).

In hindsight, while the above is something I would like to do from time to time, I was more trying to get at functionality like this:

```
blah <- function(x) {
  x$position <- 1:nrow(x)
  x$count <- nrow(x)
  return(x)
}

ddply(mtcars, .(cyl,am), function(x) blah(x))
```

Comment: I think `do()` is the general answer for you question, but it's a pain with this example because `table` doesn't return a data frame, nor is it all that easy to convert to the data frame you want.

Comment: This is just a generic, reproducible example for coding purposes. I'd like to push it beyond table.

Comment: Have updated the question, which makes it different given the nuances of table, but still getting to the same broad point.

Comment: As noted by Gregor, you could use `do` in this case. With the `blah` function it would be `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl, am) %>% do(blah(.))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning my and docendo's comments into an answer, this is what `do()` is for.

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl, am) %>% do(blah(.))
# same results as
plyr::ddply(mtcars, plyr::.(cyl, am), function(x) blah(x))
# same as plyr with no anonymous function in this case
plyr::ddply(mtcars, plyr::.(cyl, am), blah)
```

Because `blah` is taking in your full data frame (at least in terms of columns) and returning a data frame, you don't need the anonymous function call.

A lot is similar between `dplyr` and `ddply`, if you want to add columns, you use `mutate`, if you want to collapse grouping variables with aggregate functions, you use `summarise`. `do` is the dplyr equivalent of doing something else to each piece of data, but it needs to return a data frame.

Comment: Thanks Gregor. Did you know of a way to get this working with table as in the first part of the question? do obviously won't work given table doesn't return a data frame. Unless there's a better function for getting 'table' like (cross tab) output? I generally use ctab from catspec but would have the same issue with that.

Comment: do() obviously just missed the cut for the intro vignette :) http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html

Comment: @nzcoops It's not the cleanest write-up for dplyr integration but [here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28438983/903061) using `reshape2::dcast` with `fun.aggregate = length()`. (Coincidentally, it's the question I answered just before this one.)